# How to maximize $\sum_{i=n}^n x_i I_i$ given $\|x\|_1=n$ and i.i.d. $I_i=1$ w.p. $p$ and $0$ otherwise?

Tags: probability, optimization

Given $p\in\mathbb R^+$ and $n\in\mathbb N^+$, let $\{I_i\}$ be i.i.d. random indicators, each is $1$ w.p. $p$.

How should we choose a non-negative integer vector $x\in\mathbb N^n$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n$, that maximizes the threshold $M$ for which
$$
\Pr[\sum_{i=1}^nI_i\cdot x_i\ge M]\ge 0.05\qquad{}?
$$

---

I am trying to analyze a load-balancing scheme with $1/p$ bins where $n$ balls (of different sizes) may be thrown randomly into the bins and I want each bin to have at most $M$ ``work'' (sum of sizes mapped to it) to do with probability 95\% (without caring about how it affects other bins).
The answer to the above problem would be the worst-case input to the scheme.

Comment: Ambiguities: (i) What do $\sum_i x_i$ and $\sum_i I_i$ mean? (what are the actual limits of the sums?)  (ii) Do we choose $(x_1, ..., x_n, ...)$ with knowledge of the realizations of $(I_1, ..., I_n)$ or not?

Comment: @Michael - we choose the $x_i$'s, and then the random variables $I_i$'s are drawn. Let me update the limits. Thanks!

Comment: Minor comment: If $p\geq 0.05$ then $M^*=n$ and is achieved by $x=(n,0,0,...,0)$.  In general for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have $M^* \geq \lfloor n/k\rfloor$ if $1-(1-p)^k\geq 0.05$. If $n$ is even, I conjecture that $M^*=n/2$ if $1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{19/5}\leq p<0.05$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Michael, and sorry for the late reply. In my application, $p\ll 0.05$ (say, $p=10^{-5}$).  I don't mind assuming that $n$ is even if it simplifies the analysis. 
Could you please explain how you came to that conjecture :) ?

Comment: Let $M^*(p)$ be the optimal threshold as a function of $p$. The lower bound I give in the above comment shows that $M^*(p) \geq \lfloor n/k \rfloor$ where $k$ is the smallest positive integer that satisfies $(1-p)^k\leq 0.95$. So the lower bound is a piecewise-constant function of $p$. It turns out this lower bound gives the exact value of $M^*(p)$ for the cases: (i)  $p \geq 0.05$; (ii) $p<1-(0.95)^{1/n}$. Perhaps it is exact always? Note that the (probability) solution to $1-(1-p)^2=0.05$ is $1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{19/5}$.

Comment: Interesting! Any ideas on how such thing can be upper bounded?